# Grammatically, is the time span mentioned in Revelation 20:4 limited to only the topic of the martyrs' involvement in the Kingdom of Christ?

Tags: revelation

*I saw the souls of those who had been beheaded because of their testimony of Jesus...They came to life and reigned with Christ a thousand years* (Rev. 20:4)*

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the 1000 years occurs six times in Rev 20 with the following meanings:

- V2: Satan bound for 1000 years
- V3: Satan cannot deceive anyone during the 1000 years and will be set free for short while after the 1000 years
- V4: The ones given authority to judge (including those who had been beheaded and those who had not worshiped the beast, etc) are resurrected and reign with Christ for 1000 years
- V5: The rest of the dead did not come to life for 1000 years
- V6: The righteous reign with Christ 1000 years
- V7: Satan is released from prison after 1000 years

Thus, in V4 the martyrs are among the righteous who:

- are resurrected at the beginning of the 1000 years
- reign with Christ 1000 years

Comment: (Dottard) Excellent listing of the topics in Rev 20!  Mainly about Satan and the martyrs.  And I find it revealing that there was NO list containing topics like (1)  Gentile servitude, (2)Rebuilt temple, (3) Davidic throne, (4) Animal sacrifices, (5) Resurrected King David!  The list above excluded these, it seems.

Comment: @raygrant - quite correct - many claim far too much based on what is not said (and their imagination) rather than what is actually said.